# Hibernate - Translating "Legacy" Criteria to JPA Critera to implement a Generic DAO

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am attempting to use a generic DAO pattern using Hibernate by referencing this [article](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/GenericDataAccessObjects#jive_content_id_An_implementation_with_Hibernate).

However, the GenericHibernateDAO class utilizes the Hibernate queries which have subsequently been deprecated. I am attempting to use the pattern, but update it with the currently supported JPA Criteria API. However, I am struggling with how to "build" queries in the "findByCriteria" method.

This is the code form the article using the legacy Criteria classes.

```
    /** 
 * Use this inside subclasses as a convenience method. 
 */  
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  
protected List<T> findByCriteria(Criterion... criterion) {  
    Criteria crit = getSession().createCriteria(getPersistentClass());  
    for (Criterion c : criterion) {  
        crit.add(c);  
    }  
    return crit.list();
```

}

Presently, this is my present attempt at reworking it to use the JPA Criteria API.

```
protected List<T> findByCriteria(Criterion... criterion) {
   CriteriaBuilder builder = getSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
   CriteriaQuery<T> criteria = builder.createQuery(getPersistentClass());
   Root<T> root = criteria.from(getPersistentClass());
   criteria.select(root);               
   // Not sure what to do here
   for(Criterion c: criterion) {
      criteria.where()
    }

    return session.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
}
```

Specifically, the original code uses Criterion to build a query within a for loop. To my understanding, this would make the method very flexible. However, I am struggling to achieve this same effect with JPA Criteria.  For example, to my understanding, usage of the JPA Criteria API requires that one already know something about the query, for example whether or not the WHERE clause involves an EQUAL TO, GREATER THAN, or similar, restriction. I understand that the findByCriteria method signature will likely need to be altered to accept something aside from Criterion, but I am not sure what yet.

I have looked over the Hibernate docs and other online resources, but have not found anything quite like I am looking for.

Any advice would be appreciated.